# C#. При добавлении второй формы(диалогового окна), форма скрывается за основной формой. Как исправить данную проблему?

Tags: c#, winforms

Вот код открытия той самой диалоговой(модульной) формы:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.BringToFront();
        form.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Но при открытии данной второй формы она скрывается за основной:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже если убрать BringToFront(), ничего не измениться. Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: А у вас точно две формы? Или может все-таки 3 формы: первая - та с которой стартует программа, а из нее вы запускаете остальные 2, которые перекрывают друг друга.

Comment: Точно две формы. Первая что большая и слева сверху надпись Server. И как раз когда на этой форме я нажимаю на кнопку "Добавить", выплывает вторая форма, белая. Только вот эта белая форма почему то за основной скрывается.

Comment: Формы по умолчанию открываются поверх других. У вас там случайно нигде нет кода, который пытается менять расположения окон? Там, к примеру, на основной форме или уже внутри второй?

Comment: Если формы действительно 2, то такой случай невозможен. Я только что проверил; создал 2 форму, на первую форму добавил кнопку и вызвал `form.ShowDialog();` нажатие на первую форму даже не дает на нее переключится, вторая всегда сверху первой.

Comment: Нету. Вторая форма вообще чиста и девственна. Только вот я добавлял метроформу для дизайна public partial class Form1 : MetroForm и ничего более. Но посмотрев пару уроков по данной библиотеке я увидел, что там с этим проблем нет, и дополнительные формы не скрываются за основными.

Comment: Как стартует `Form1` ? Покажите код из `Program.cs`.

Comment: [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

Comment: Уберите наследование от `MetroForm` и проверьте работу еще раз.

Comment: Уже так сделал в двух формах, результат не изменился.

Comment: Можно конечно попробовать принудительно добавить владельца ’form.showDialog(this)’, но не факт, что это поможет. Обычно ещё можно попробовать закомментировать остальной код приложения по максимум в попытке найти источник проблем. Может какой-нибудь ’focus()’ найдется. Есть ещё вероятность редкого бага - можно проверить создав чистый проект только с двумя чистыми формами и вызовом, но шанс почти нулевой.

Comment: ......  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Огромное спасибо Alex Krass'у. form.showDialog(this) действительно помог. А теперь вопрос, почему?

Comment: Вот только теперь при закрытии данной формы выдает: "Создана циклическая ссылка на элемент управления. Элемент управления не может являться владельцем или родителем для самого себя."

Comment: У меня только подозрение, что какой-то участок кода вызывает конфликт. Но на приведенном участке можно только строить самые разнообразные догадки. Я бы посмотрел на полный код или проект. Если нет желания показывать - то попробуйте поотрубать все остальные части кода или даже создать новый проект только с диалоговым окном и потом к нему навесить функционал, пока опять не упретесь в эту проблему.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/wJFZpuJMu8gT5w вот весь проект.

Comment: По коду вроде ничего криминально, но сам проект не открывается. Там отсутствует почему-то сам .csproj и пишет, что не может его найти по пути "c:\users\gutsc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5.csproj". В архиве ощущение, что отсутствует часть. Но тогда странно, что там лежат Form1 файлы.

Comment: Я уже создал новый проект и сделал всё заново. С новым проектом всё заработало. Видимо просто проект крякнулся.